# Do you rebase onto, with (or some other preposition) another branch?

Tags: git, terminology, rebase

I most often hear colleagues say *I rebased my branch with master* but is this the 'correct' way to say it? Do you rebase onto a ref or do you rebase with a ref? Are both ways acceptable/accurate?

Comment: I should go to sleep, but [`git rebase --onto` is a thing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: Technically, you rebase onto a commit. Using `git rebase --onto <thing>` tells Git precisely which one; using `git rebase <upstream>` without `--onto` tells Git to use `upstream` to find the target commit. With no arguments, Git finds the `<upstream>` from the branch's upstream setting.

Comment: What people *call* that is not exactly a programming question, though what kind of question it is, is harder to say. Doesn't fit on english.stackexchange.com, I think...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search for both expressions in [`git/git`](https://github.com/git/git/) (the Git source code), you will get:

For `rebase with`:

```
D:\git\git>git grep -i "rebase with"
Documentation/git-pull.txt:When set to `preserve` (deprecated in favor of `merges`), rebase with the
Documentation/git-rebase.txt:- Start an interactive rebase with `git rebase -i <commit>^`, ...
Documentation/git-rebase.txt:- Continue the rebase with `git rebase --continue`.
...
```

"with a branch" is never used.

Regarding "rebase on":

```
po/bg.po:msgid "Cannot rebase onto multiple branches."
po/bg.po:msgid "rebase onto given branch instead of upstream"
po/bg.po:msgid "invalid branch.%s.merge; cannot rebase onto > 1 branch"
```

So you clearly are rebasing onto a branch, not "with a branch".

That is in the very definition of the [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) command:

> Reapply commits **on** top of another base tip